# How to use javascript to remove external divs

Tags: javascript, html, class

Hi all and thanks for reading. I have spent days trying to achieve this:

I have an element on my website page which loads divs from an external sources.

Well, I don't want to have some divs. If I inspect the element and delete them, I get away with it. I want to make it automatic.

There are 3 divs which have different classes, my idea is to get these classes and delete the elements.

NOTE: These not-wanted divs load after my website, I think, so the script needs to wait until they are loaded and only then "kill" them.

Here is my code (not working):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
window.onload=function()  //executes when the page finishes loading
{
    setTimeout(func1, 10000);

};
function func1()
{
              var child = document.getElementsByClassName("cuadrado adblock1 advertisement ad2");
           var child2 = document.getElementsByClassName("vertical adblock1 advertisement");

          // Remove the child element from the document
            var aux = child.parentNode;
            aux.removeChild(child);
            var eux = child2.parentNode;
            eux.removeChild(child2);
 }

</script>
```

Comment: Unless the external site is willing to be modified, you can't do that due to the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: would a simple CSS display: none fix it?

Comment: No it doesn't, I tried already. The problem might me the div css external si display:block;

my display:none; doesn't work

P.S. What abot removing the DVI, not just deleting it?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is: document.getElementsByClassName() returns an object - possibly with multiple elements.  You need to call .parentNode on a single element, not on the object returned by document.getElementsByClassName.  See below.

```
var child = document.getElementsByClassName('child');

// aux = undefined
var aux = child.parentNode;

// aux = an element...
var aux = child[0].parentNode;
```

I would recommend something like the following:

```
var child = document.getElementsByClassName("cuadrado adblock1 advertisement ad2");
for(var i = 0; i < child.length; i++) {
  child[i].parentNode.removeChild(child[i]);
};
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Jus tried this with no luck: (iframe not previewing in jsfiddle)

https://jsfiddle.net/u5g0L8n4/

Comment: I was unaware that you were referencing iframes, you should have put that in the original question.  If you attempt to run scripts on cross-domain iframes, you will most likely run into errors - see below.  Aka: no easy solution for that problem.

`Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "https://example.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://example2.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.`